# SQL Server get all integers up to N that are NOT IN table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql server database table containing a normalized subversion log. However, some revisions are missing. How do I get all missing revisions?

I tried

```
SELECT Revision + 1
  FROM SvnLog
  WHERE Revision + 1 NOT IN (SELECT Revision FROM SvnLog)
```

but that leaves out anything after the first missing revision in the case of a missing range. For example, if 100-110 are missing, it only picks up 100.

I also tried

```
WITH revs(rev) AS (
  SELECT 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT revs.rev + 1
  FROM revs
  WHERE revs.rev <90000
)

SELECT rev
FROM revs
WHERE rev NOT IN (SELECT Revision from SVNLog)
```

but the recursion in the CTE was cut off at 100 and I have thousands of revisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `OPTION` which control recursion dept for `CTE`. You can use `MAXRECURSION 0` which removes limit.

```
WITH revs(rev) AS (
  SELECT 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT revs.rev + 1
  FROM revs
  WHERE revs.rev <90000
)

SELECT rev
FROM revs
WHERE rev NOT IN (SELECT Revision from SVNLog)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I find this problem is easier to approach using lengths of gaps in the numbers, rather than listing each one out individually.  After all, doing recursion for tens of thousands or hundreds of thousands of rows is likely to be less performant than you would like.

You don't specify which version of SQL Server you are using.  In SQL Server 2012, this would be most easily done using `lag()`.  But here is a more generic version:

```
select (revision + 1) as gapStart, (nextrevision) - 1 as gapEnd
from (select l.revision,
             (select min(l2.revision)
              from SVNLog l2
              where l2.revision > l.revision
             ) as NextRevision
      from SVNLog l
     ) l
where nextrevision <> revision + 1;
```

For performance, you want an index on `SVNLog(Revision)`.

This also misses initial gaps and certain other details.  Before filling those in, though, I don't know if this format meets your needs.

By the way, if you want to know if there are *any* gaps at all, you can just do:

```
select (max(revision) - min(revision) + 1) - count(distinct revision)
from SVNLog l;
```

If there are no gaps, then this will return `0`.  Otherwise, there are gaps.

Comment: I know there are definitely gaps. If I run the first query, I get an error saying `revision` can't be selected because it isn't contained in an aggregate function or a `GROUP BY` clause. The other answer meets my needs but thank you for your help!